# How to show all factors of a number?(Edited)

Tags: java, methods, static-methods, factorization

```
    I need help on fixing my FactorX method. It needs to be like this>>.. The factors of x. (For example, if x is 120 then the factors would be 2, 2, 2, 3, 5). 



            ppublic static String factorX(long x){
            String factor="";
            long number = x;
            long i = 2;  
            while (i < number) {  
                    if (number % i == 0) {
                    factor += i+", "+i+", "; 
                    number /= i;

                } else {
                    i++;
                }
            }

            return factor;
```

I need my method to show all factors, now it is showing only one. I was told about List, but I cannot make to work.

Comment: What exactly should factorX() return? currently it always return a single integer number, as a string.

Comment: For example is the number is 120 then it should display the factors 2, 2, 2, 3, 5

Comment: Hint: once you find a divisor i, add it to the output and continue looking for divisors in number/i. Also, think about the loop end criteria.

Comment: public static String factorX(long x){
        String factor= "";
        long number = x;
        long i=1;
        
        while ( i <= number ){
         if((number % i ==0)){
          factor+=number %i +"";
         }
        }
  return factor;
  
  
 }

Comment: I edit it, but I don't get any return?

Comment: You forgot to update number to be number / i.

Comment: Yes I just added that I just need to have a list of all the factors number..

Comment: You should post a new question or, even better, comment on my answer if it doesn't work as expected. One thing I just noticed is that `while (i <= number && i < x)` should be used as otherwise the last factor is missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to increase `i` if `i` no longer divides the number. You can do this by dividing the number by `i`, or increase it otherwise:

```
    long i = 2; // start with 2, not 1
    while (i < number) { // and don't end with the number itself
        if (number % i == 0) {
            factor += i+", "; // add i, not x; and add it to factor, not to number
            number /= i;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return factor; // return factor, not number
```

This also fixes the output to contain commas. You could alternatively use a `List<Integer>` to add all divisors to if you don't simply want to print the list, but use it in the code.

Comment: Define factor as `List<Integer factor = new ArrayList<Integer>` and use `factor.add(i)` to add a number to the list. You can then e.g. loop the list with `for (int f : factor) { ... }`. Take a look at the other methods in the List interface for more information.

Comment: Is this the only way, I am trying with this but I am afraid I am not using object oriented

Comment: There are possibly infinite ways to do this, this is just an easy example which doesn't require much code. Also you shouldn't need to care about OOP much while you're still learning to program ;)

Comment: public static String factorX(long x){
  
  List<Integer> factor = new ArrayList<Integer>;
        long number = x;
        long i = 2;  
        while (i < number) {  
         for (int f : factor){
            if (number % i == 0) {
                factor += i+", "+i+", "; 
                number /= i;
                factor.add(i);
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
        }
        return factor;

Comment: the arrayList<integer> needs to be in the factorX method or on the main method?

Comment: You should try to understand the code before making any modifications to it that you don't understand either. `for (int f : factor)` loops all items in the list, which is definitely not what my code does.